# How can I develop with maximum compatibility to old browsers?

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer

I'm at a job developing a dashboard application on the web.

There are about 50+ people working here (I'm the only programmer). While some computers have a decent version of Chrome installed, most only have IE to work with.

The newest version of Internet Explorer they have is IE10. Most have IE9 installed; some even have IE8.

I've already ditched Flexbox for the styling, which doesn't work on IE10 and down, but other features that work on modern browsers don't work on those older browsers at all, like scripts and some other features.

My question is: How can I get all these browsers to display the pages in the same way?

Comment: Maybe take a look at http://caniuse.com

Comment: write plain html & pure javascript

Comment: I have bad news: you'll have to use IE8 yourself, at least as main developer tool. To make it worse, you'll possibly need to run it inside a virtual machine.

Comment: Question edit suggestion: "What can be done to fix browser (mostly IE) variances?".

Answer (score 1):

First, define the "official" list of supported browsers and OS's. It appears that you are working in a Microsoft environment so variations of IE on Windows may be the norm and not so much of Safari on Macs.

While making this list, convey to the decision makers that a bigger list usually means more time and effort to get everything working the same way for all of the supported configurations. Sometimes it makes more sense to upgrade a user using IE6 to something newer rather than spending weeks on an IE6 specific issue. (Re: IE6, do what you can to keep it off the list, doing so will save you a lot of time and aggravation.)

Another ramification of this list is that you, the developer, will need to have access to every configuration on the list so that you can test each supported configuration. Again, bigger list means more time developing AND testing.

Note that this list will change over time. Consider doing an annual review to revise this list as your environment evolves.

Once you've done the above, then it is a matter of recording the browser/OS variances and deciding which has the highest priority to fix. Fixes can be as simple as a one line CSS change or complex so as to require re-writing several pages.

If and when you get stuck, post another question on SO for ideas on how to fix specific browser/OS variances with your web dashboard application.  Good Luck